# Как правильно создавать заглушки для классов с асинхронными методами в Ninject.MockingKernel?

Tags: c#, .net, юнит-тесты, ninject, moq

Имеется класс, который использует `Ninject` для получения экземпляра репозитория:

```
public class ClosedClass
{
    public String DoWork()
    {
        var repo = AppStatic.Kernel.Get<IRepo>();
        return repo.GetData();
    }

    public async Task<String> DoWorkAsync()
    {
        var repo = AppStatic.Kernel.Get<IRepo>();
        return await repo.GetDataAsync();
    }
}
```

Как видно из кода конкретный экземпляр класса, реализующего `IRepo` каждый экземпляр класса `ClosedClass` получает от ядра `Ninject`, экземпляр которого хранится в статическом открытом поле статического класса `AppStatic`. Вот, собственно, код класса:

```
public static class AppStatic
{
    public static IKernel Kernel { get; private set; }

    static AppStatic()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();
    }

    public static void SetKernel(IKernel kernelInstance)
    {
        Kernel = kernelInstance;
    }
}
```

Класс `ClosedClass` необходимо протестировать при помощи MSTest + Ninject + Ninject.MockingKernel + Moq, при чём тестируются оба метода (синхронный `DoWork()` и асинхронный `DoWorkAsync()`). Собственно, с тестированием синхронного метода проблем не возникает. Создаётся экземпляр класса, затем ядро `Niject`, которое позвозяет привязывать моки к интерфейсам, на указанном моке, собственно, указывается желаемое значение:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSync()
{
    var c = new SAMPLEMOQ.ClosedClass();
    var kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();
    kernel
        .GetMock<IRepo>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetData())
        .Returns("FAKE");
    AppStatic.SetKernel(kernel);


    Trace.WriteLine(c.DoWork());

}
```

В результате выполнения теста в `output` выводится строка `FAKE` - отлично!
Тем не менее, при тестировании асинхронного метода `DoWorkAsync()` аналогичным образом, тест просто начинает выполнение и не останавливается, пока я сам не отменяю процесс выполнения. Код юнит-теста для асинхронного метода `DoWorkAsync()`:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestASync()
{
    var c = new SAMPLEMOQ.ClosedClass();

    var kernel = new MoqMockingKernel();

    kernel
        .GetMock<IRepo>()
        .Setup(m => m.GetDataAsync())
        .Returns(new Task<String>(() => "Fake"));
    AppStatic.SetKernel(kernel);


    Trace.WriteLine(await c.DoWorkAsync());
}
```

**Вопрос:** почему этот тест не выполняется, при чём даже не выдаёт никакую ошибку?

**PS**: Тесты запускаю НЕ параллельно, каждый в отдельности.

1. OS: Windows 10
2. IDE: VS 2015 Update 3
3. Platform: .NET Framework 4.6
4. Ninject: v3.2.2.0 (net46)
5. Ninject.MockingKernel: v3.2.2.0 (net46)
6. Ninject.MockingKernel.Moq: v3.2.2.0 (net46)
7. Moq: v4.5.2.1 (net46)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
kernel
    .GetMock<IRepo>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetDataAsync())
    .Returns(new Task<String>(() => "Fake"));
```

на

```
kernel
    .GetMock<IRepo>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetDataAsync())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult("Fake"));
```

или

```
kernel
    .GetMock<IRepo>()
    .Setup(m => m.GetDataAsync())
    .Returns(
        async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(20);
            return "Fake";
        });
```

(смотря что требуется).

Дело вот в чём. Если убрать всю обвязку, то по сути происходит

```
await new Task<String>(() => "Fake");
```

Однако `new Task(...)` создаёт не стартованную задачу (со статусом *Created*), такой `await` не завершится.